# net view command won't list share despite being present in the File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking

I am trying to view my network share via the `net view` command.

When I run it I get this output:

```
C:\Users\bchee>net view
Server Name            Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\DESKTOP-A3MU3KR
The command completed successfully.
```

`\\DESKTOP-A3MU3KR` is the name of the local laptop.

However, as can be seen here:

[image: Remote folder]

I am able to access the C drive of the remote computer `Desktop-30uosmd`.

Why is `Desktop-30uosmd` not showing up in the `net view` output?